# How can I add extension method to existing class

Tags: typescript

I want to add method extension to existing class, but I don't know how. I tried this:

[image]

But I always receive `Property 'addAssembler' doesnt exist on type 'Container'` error.

Answer (score 8):

You can just just expant class members by defining interface with same name and adding new methods to it:

foo2.ts:

```
class Foo {
    spam?: string;
    bar() {
        console.log('Foo#bar');
    }
}
```

app.ts:

```
import { Foo } from './foo2';

declare module './foo2' {
    interface Foo {
        foo(): void;
    }
}

Foo.prototype.foo = function(this: Foo) {
    console.log('Foo#foo', this.spam);
}

const f = new Foo();
f.spam = 'eggs';
f.bar();
f.foo();
```

Comment: updated to work with your use case. And it really works on my env. i.e typescript 2.7.1

Comment: Looking at your comments to other answer just confirm that it doesn't work with reexported symbol . You must use original module name  `declare module` then it works but this is far from being elegant solution.

Comment: The exported class can't be exported with `default`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a module augmentation:

```
declare module 'inversify' {
    export interface Container {
        addAssembler(): void
    }
}
```

You can add the declaration above in your `ts` file where you add the method to the `Container` prototype.

**Edit**

Unfortunately the way `Container` is defined prevents augmentation.  We can merge classes from modules with interfaces, but they have to be defined as `export class Container {}`. In this case container is exported as `class Container {} export { Container }`. This prevents augmentation unfortunately.

Comment: I doesn't work. I get `TS2693: 'Container' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` on line `3`

Comment: @JaSHin is the original type a class ?

Comment: Yes. `declare class Container implements interfaces.Container {...}`

Comment: @JaSHin the type is re-exported from another definition .. trying to figure out how to augment it ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom class by extending the original class. In your case, it would be:

```
import { Container } from 'inversify'

class CustomContainer extends Container {
  addAssembler() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

export class DIContainer {
  constructor() {
    let container = new CustomContainer()
    container.addAssembler()
  }
}

export const globalContainer = new DIContainer()
```