# Extending 3rd party interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, botframework

I am currently trying to merge declarations from a 3rd party library called `botbuilder`. It has a interface called `IPrompts` and I'm trying to add a method to it called `luisPrompt`. The type declaration file looks like the following: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts On line 3574 is the interface I'm trying to extend (which it gives instructions below the interface on how to do this.

I have the following inside of a `botbuilder.d.ts` file:

```
    import * as builder from 'botbuilder';
    import { IPromptTextOptions, Session, TextOrMessageType } from 'botbuilder';

    declare global {
      interface IPrompts {
         luisPrompt(session: Session, prompt: TextOrMessageType, options?: IPromptTextOptions): void;
      }
    }
```

At runtime, I'm having no issues, however, when I go to build it's throwing the following error: `error TS2339: Property 'luisPrompt' does not exist on type 'IPrompts'`.

Any feedback greatly appreciated, tried several different things, no dice!

Comment: What do you mean `I have the following inside of a botbuilder.d.ts`? actually, your code works fine on my side, both at runtime and during tsc building. BTW, how  you build your code?

Comment: Build script looks like the following: `&quot;build-ts&quot;: &quot;tsc -p tsconfig.json &amp;&amp; tsc -p test/tsconfig.json&quot;` I&#39;m declaring a definition file since im creating a custom prompt that does not exist on `IPrompt`

Comment: Could you provide what your `tsconfig.json` like?

Comment: I pasted my config here: https://pastiebin.com/5b4d7dfb3cd44 also, my definition files are located in `src/types`

Comment: Strangely, your configuration works perfectly on myside, and my local typescript version is `2.8.1`

Comment: At first look, what you're doing wrong is exending 'global' module. botbuilder is not a global module, so you should (probably) `declare 'botbuilder' { interface IPrompts {...} }`. But i'm not sure. Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058298/how-can-i-add-extension-method-to-existing-class#50058440 ? Hope this fits definition of "any feedback".